# nginx password protect not working

Tags: nginx, password

I'm having problems setting a password on the landing page of my website.
I've seen this question asked a few times and tried the upvoted fixes in each post. So far I've tried changing permissions of .htpasswd , changing the location of .htpasswd, using the absolute path location of .htpasswd, and placing auth_basic and auth_basic_user_file directives outside of 'location' and in the main 'server' block but the pop-up asking for username and password is still not showing up when I go to my URL. What I'd like is for a password prompt to pop up when I browse to my main URL not any specific directory or file. I've looked and followed through many tutorials and have used the htpasswd command to create the .htpasswd file. From what I understand this is the correct configuration of /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default. What am I doing wrong here?

This is my config file:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    root /var/www/html;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    return 310 https://$server_name$request_uri;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
            auth_basic "Under Construction";
            auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
    }
 }
```

Comment: What is the exact output of `curl -v` when you make a request? What is the output in nginx log files?

Comment: I fixed the general issue, I had an extra server block from a SSL set up I was doing. Once I moved the SSL info into the main server block the pop-up appeared. The problem now is that after I log-in I get a 500 Internal Server Error.

Comment: The 500 error was due to permissions on the .htaccess file chmod 0755'd the .htaccess file and the problem was fixed.

Comment: I assume you meant `.htpasswd` here.

Comment: Lol yes.. Long day

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `return` statement overrides the `location` statement.

You need to have a configuration like this:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    root /var/www/html;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    location = / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
            auth_basic "Under Construction";
            auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
    }

    location / {
        return 310 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    }
```

}

So, the `location = /` statement matches exactly one path, here it is the root URI for the site.

Then the `location /` matches all the other paths on the site.

nginx parses `location` block so that the `location` with `=` is always used if multiple `location` blocks match the same path.

Comment: Thanks for this but unfortunately the problem still persists. Just in case anyone is wondering I AM doing a 'sudo service nginx restart' after every attempt to fix this issue.